# Error during traning my model with pytorch, stack expects each tensor to be equal size

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation

I am using MMSegmentainon library to train my model for instance image segmentation, during the traingin, I craete the model(Vision Transformer) and when I try to train  the model using this:

I get this error:

> RuntimeError:CaughtRuntimeErrorinDataLoaderworkerprocess0.OriginalTraceback(mostrecentcalllast):
> File"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py",line287,in
> _worker_loop
> data=fetcher.fetch(index)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 47, infetch
> returnself.collate_fn(data)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mmcv/parallel/collate.py", line 81, in collateforkeyinbatch[0]
> File"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mmcv/parallel/collate.py",line81,in
> <dictcomp>
> forkey in batch[0]
> File"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mmcv/parallel/collate.py",line59,incollatestacked.append(default_collate(padded_samples))
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 56, indefault_collate
> returntorch.stack(batch,0,out=out)
>
> RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [1, 256, 256, 256] at entry0 and[1,256,256] at entry3

** I must also mention that I have tested my own dataset with other models available in their library but all of them works properly.

tried :

```
model=build_segmentor(cfg.model,train_cfg=cfg.get('train_cfg'),test_cfg=cfg.get('test_cfg'))train_segmentor(model,datasets,cfg,distributed=False,validate=True,
meta=dict())
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that images in your dataset might not have the same size, as in the VIT model https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.11929, you are using an MLP model,

if it was not the case, it is worth checking if your labels are all in the expected dimension.
presumably, MMsegmentattion expects the output to be just the annotation map (a 2D array).
It is recommended that you revise your dataset and prepare the annotation map.

Comment: thanks,the problem was as you mentioned. after I resized all the pictures into the same size I did'nt get the error anymore.